# Extracting APK from App Bundle failed because of java heap space using bundletool

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-app-bundle

We are shifting from Android APK to Android bundle. Android studio creates bundle successfully but when i try to extract APK from bundle using bundletool it fails because of **Heap out of memory**.

I tried to upload an app bundle on Play Console for internal testing but it failed without showing any error.

Size of my bundle is almost 125mb which is less than allowed 150mb.

I eliminated some code for testing and when app bundle was less than 100mb everything worked fine.

How can I increase the size of heap to work with greater app bundle.

FYI: We export Unity project to Android.

Comment: You are using app bundle from android studio or from command line? If it's from command line, what is the flags you are passing to the command?

Comment: From command line, i wasn't passing any flags.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the -Xms flag? (As the answer bellow)

Answer (score 2):

You can call the bundletool .jar from command line using java command and pass the max heap size as an argument (-Xms64m, for example) to it.
Once you have the bundletool .jar, you can run it with the command:
OBS: Replace the ..... with your project information

```
java -Xmx5G -jar bundletool-all-0.7.1.jar build-apks --bundle=../..../app.aab --output=bundleapks.apks --ks=../..../keystore --ks-pass=pass:..... --ks-key-alias=.... --key-pass=pass:....
```

Sources:

https://github.com/google/bundletool/issues/37

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control

Comment: How até tou passinho the flags?

Comment: java -Xms2G -jar bundletool-all-0.3.3.jar build-apks --bundle=../../xx.aab --output=xx.apks

Comment: Even aab file is not uploading on Google Play Console.

Comment: I mean when you try to generate the apk

Comment: Yes same error. Can it be because of lots of resource files created by unity?